# Change an element id with an option from a drop down list

Tags: php, javascript, html, replace, drop-down-menu

Couples of days I'm trying to change an element id with a value from a drop down list. For example:

Drop-down:
Item 1
Item 2
Item 3
....
Item n

The element:
< div id="$the_selected_item" > < /div >


I'm not very good at php and javascript, so I would appreciate it if you could help me,

Thanks.

Comment: I think this link can make help  http://api.jquery.com/change/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a jsfiddle with:

```
<select id="test">
<option value="item1">item1</option>
<option value="item2">item2</option>
<option value="item3">item3</option>
<option value="item4">item4</option>
</select>

<div id="selected">test</div > ​
```

and this jquery

```
$("#test").change( function() {
     jQuery('#selected').attr('id', jQuery(this).val());
});​
```

you can see it there : http://jsfiddle.net/c3teF/4/

It takes the value of the option and transfers it to the div.